OpenTelemetry agent logging WARN message for (Instrument db.client.connections.max has recorded multiple values for the same attributes)
I have a application where it connects to two mutiple databases. One is IBM DB2 and one is Postgres.
In the logs I seen multiple WARN messages that says following:
[otel.javaagent 2024-07-02 14:06:33:077 +0200] [PeriodicMetricReader-1] WARN io.opentelemetry.sdk.metrics.internal.state.AsynchronousMetricStorage - Instrument db.client.connections.idle.min has recorded multiple values for the same attributes: {pool.name="HikariPool-(my-app-name)-DB2"}
My database config for these two databases is:
object DatabaseConfig {
    private fun db2HikariConfig(): HikariConfig {
        val db2Properties: PropertiesConfig.Db2Properties = PropertiesConfig.Db2Properties()
        return HikariConfig().apply {
            maximumPoolSize = 10
            minimumIdle = 1
            poolName = "HikariPool-${PropertiesConfig.Configuration().naisAppName}-DB2"
            connectionTestQuery = "select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1"
            dataSource =
                DB2SimpleDataSource().apply {
                    driverType = 4
                    enableNamedParameterMarkers = DB2BaseDataSource.YES
                    databaseName = db2Properties.name
                    serverName = db2Properties.host
                    portNumber = db2Properties.port.toInt()
                    currentSchema = db2Properties.schema
                    connectionTimeout = 1000
                    commandTimeout = 10000
                    user = db2Properties.username
                    setPassword(db2Properties.password)
                }
        }
    }

    private fun postgresHikariConfig(): HikariConfig {
        val postgresProperties: PropertiesConfig.PostgresProperties = PropertiesConfig.PostgresProperties()
        return HikariConfig().apply {
            poolName = "HikariPool-${PropertiesConfig.Configuration().naisAppName}-POSTGRES"
            maximumPoolSize = 5
            minimumIdle = 1
            dataSource =
                PGSimpleDataSource().apply {
                    if (PropertiesConfig.isLocal()) {
                        user = postgresProperties.adminUsername
                        password = postgresProperties.adminPassword
                    }
                    serverNames = arrayOf(postgresProperties.host)
                    databaseName = postgresProperties.databaseName
                    portNumbers = intArrayOf(postgresProperties.port.toInt())
                    connectionTimeout = Duration.ofSeconds(10).toMillis()
                    maxLifetime = Duration.ofMinutes(30).toMillis()
                    initializationFailTimeout = Duration.ofMinutes(30).toMillis()
                }
        }
    }

    fun db2DataSource(): HikariDataSource = HikariDataSource(db2HikariConfig())

    fun postgresDataSource(
        hikariConfig: HikariConfig = postgresHikariConfig(),
        role: String = PropertiesConfig.PostgresProperties().user,
    ): HikariDataSource {
        return when {
            PropertiesConfig.isLocal() -> HikariDataSource(hikariConfig)
            else ->
                HikariCPVaultUtil.createHikariDataSourceWithVaultIntegration(
                    hikariConfig,
                    PropertiesConfig.PostgresProperties().vaultMountPath,
                    role,
                )
        }
    }

    fun postgresMigrate(dataSource: HikariDataSource = postgresDataSource(role = PropertiesConfig.PostgresProperties().adminUser)) {
        Flyway.configure()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .initSql("""SET ROLE "${PropertiesConfig.PostgresProperties().adminUser}"""")
            .lockRetryCount(-1)
            .load()
            .migrate()
            .migrationsExecuted
        logger.info { "Migration finished" }
    }
}

How can I fix the WARN message? Its logs like every second.
I am using OpenTelemetry agent version 2.5.0.
I have looked at a solution, but it will turn off database monitoring. So maybe not so smart as I want to monitor the connection etc.
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/discussions/10440

I removed the poolName attribute, and it solved the issue.
